# Font size not rendering properly

Tags: css

I have five Macs I can test a website on, all running OSX El Capitan and the latest versions of the major browsers. On all but one, everything is fine. However, on that one, fonts are being rendered differently. The site uses pixel sizes to define the size of the font, (eg font-size: 20px). When text is inside a defined-width container (with an image background), it appears larger in relation to that container on this one computer. In all browsers. Regardless of screen resolution.

I've looked through the computer settings but can't find anything relevant. I need to work out what's going on because it's messing with the design.

Any clues?

Comment: I think that is because of screen resolution.

Comment: Are you using a non-webfont that may not be installed on the new computer?

Comment: I'm using a font being served from Google that isn't installed on any of the computers. It shows up just fine as the actual font, just the wrong pixel size.

The screen resolution doesn't make any difference - and it shouldn't - since both the size of the text and the size of all images etc changes as you change screen resolution. 

Zooming in or out on the browsers (Cmd+ and Cmd-) also maintains the ratios, so, whatever the zoom, the text still looks too large compared to the image.